# Lost Game Center password

Tags: apple-id, password, games, game-center

My Game Center password is lost and I can't remember the security question because it is an old account and I never wrote the password down, I also switched to a new phone.

Comment: did you look in your keychain ?

Comment: Game Center Password = Apple ID password. Have you tried https://appleid.apple.com?

Answer (score 2):

You game center password is the same as your Apple ID password. To get that recovered you will need to call Apple Support and have a iDevice that is registered with that ID already. They will send a code, which you can then relay to them. They will change your password for you. If you are a minor, you need to get an adult to do this.